# Create a Storage subclass with proto

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

I'm having a JS black out, or I'm not as good as I thought...

I want to create a class `Sites` that extends `Storage` (`localStorage` and `sessionStorage`). I want that because Storage has named items AND `.length`. Perfect for what I want.

So this I did (it's namespaced in `rweb`):

```
rweb.Sites = function Sites() {
   // There might be something useful in Storage's constructor?
  Storage.call(this);
  this.STORAGE = 'sync';
};
rweb.Sites.prototype = Object.create(Storage.prototype);
rweb.Sites.prototype.constructor = rweb.Sites;
```

I think that's how I usually do JS classes...: create constructor, assign other prototype to it, override constructor.

I override the constructor, so that:

```
var sites = new rweb.Sites;
sites.constructor == rweb.Sites;
> true
```

It fails in the new constructor:

> TypeError: Object function Storage() { [native code] } has no method 'call'

How can function Storage not be callable? (Fair enough, it's not fully exposed.) How can I use its constructor?

If I remove the `Storage.call` from my constructor, I can create object `sites`, but then when I try to use it's interface:

```
var sites = new rweb.Sites;
> Sites {}
sites.setItem('foo', 'bar');
```

it tells me:

> TypeError: Illegal invocation

What?? If I `console.log(sites.setItem)` I can see it's really the function I mean:

> function setItem() { [native code] }

Am I doing it completely wrong or did they really not expose enough of `Storage` for it to be reusable?

BTW: I can extend `Storage` and use it:

```
Storage.prototype.foo = function() {
  return 'bar';
};
sites.foo(); // returns 'bar' and no errors
```

so the prototyping works I think...

I'm using Chrome and it will all be a Chrome extension, so it can be hightech. (I hear there's a `setPrototypeOf` coming.)

Comment: host objects don't have to behave like user-land objects. they can not behave at all, behave somewhat, or work perfectly.

Comment: So I can't reuse its logic? =( That blows. I like named items + `.length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Storage` isn't fully exposed and is not extendable.

Probably too much dangerous magic inside.